# Div contents don't float left as they should

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup for a div of content that's being dynamically pulled from a .json file:

```
<div class="subSection">
    <div ng-repeat="content in subSection.content" class="subSection_content">
            <div class="table_container">
                <p ng-if="content.type =='table_p'" ng-bind-html="content.content" class="{{content.class}}"></p>
                <ul ng-if="content.type == 'table_ul'" class="{{content.class}}">
                    <li ng-repeat="li in content.content track by $index"  ng-bind-html="li.item"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS that applies to this div:

```
div.table_container {
        background-color: #a9c7e1;
        width: 100%;
    }

    p.table_img_p {
        background-color: #0090c3;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

    .table_img_list {
        padding: 0.5em;
    }

@media only screen and (min-width: 720px){
    div.subSection {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div.subSection_content {
        width: 100%;
    }

    div.table_container {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

And here's what's it giving me instead of floating the divs to the left. It treats the elements within that div as individual divs. >.< Clearing anything at all doesn't help. Suggestions?

[image: CSS problem screen shot]

And here's the output code (HTML). Nothing odd going on in CSS.

```
<div class="subSection">
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <p class="firstP">One way that toxicity can be measured is by its specific effect on an organ or organs. The kidneys and liver are most commonly associated with toxicity because of their primary roles in metabolism, detoxification, and excretion. However, all body organs can be affected including the skin, brain, heart, lungs, and gastrointestinal organs.</p>
</div>
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <p class="table_img_p">Symptoms of Liver Damage</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <ul class="table_img_list">
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Jaundiced skin or eyes</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Abdominal pain</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Nausea</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Discolored or bloody waste secretions</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Fatigue</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Anorexia</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <p class="table_img_p">Symptoms of Kidney Damage</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <ul class="table_img_list">
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Hypertension</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Nausea</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Edema</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Fatigue</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Anorexia</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Change in urine output</li>
            <li class="ng-binding ng-scope">Chest pain and shortness of breath</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What's wanted: on mobile it should be 1 column (two blue boxes one under the other), and on larger views it should be two columns (two blue boxes next to each other). I've done styling of this kind of thing many times before and never had such difficulty styling it. Just looking for suggestions on what is going on that it doesn't want to float on "1 line" next to each other.

[image: desired outcome]

Comment: Can you provide the outputed HTML instead of the template?

Comment: Thats only half you code. Its hard to give half an answer

Comment: Output for the whole page or just the div that's troublesome? I would not be able to recreate this in a fiddle as it's a hefty beast on it's own and runs on Angular.

Comment: Just the part of the markup that is represented in your screenshot. I think I have a good idea of what's going on but would like to see the markup with the final output with all the content, classes, ids etc.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the output code.

Comment: Please post the code as code in your question instead of a screenshot. Also include the HTML for the DIVs `.subSection` and `.subSection_content`. Also the `<p>` before your `<ul>`.

Comment: Would also be helpful if you could clarify the intended result. Do you want the light blue to be below the darker blue?

Comment: Gotcha. Found a way to do this, be up in a mo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: OP has updated question with visual example since this answer was provided.**

You haven't given a clear definition of what you'd like to achieve but I'll take a stab at it.

I'm going to assume the following:

1. That the light blue DIV should be under the darker blue DIV.
2. That the darker blue DIV is the header for the light blue DIV.
3. That each dark blue DIV and light blue DIV will be treated is one item/gropu/etc.
4. That on smaller screens the *Liver Damage* group appears above the *Kidney Damage* group.
5. That on larger screens the *Liver Damage* group appears to the left of the *Kidney Damage* group.

If so, then the issue is the way you're conditionally outputting your content/markup. The template doesn't match the output markup you've provided. Each header is nested in the same set of DIVs as its associated content.

```html
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <p><!-- header --></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <ul><!-- content --></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would expect to see something like this if my assumptions are correct:

```html
<div class="subSection_content ng-scope">
    <div class="table_container">
        <p><!-- header --></p>
        <ul><!-- content --></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which match your template but not output markup. This would get you the results you are looking for with the supplied CSS, http://jsfiddle.net/kqwpheh9/. The jsFiddle doesn't include any spacing between the lists, you'll have to include that later.

It appears your `.table_container` and `.subSection_content` DIVs might be redundant, among other markup considerations.

Comment: that's exactly what I have in my non-rendered code. See the first html snipped in my problem description. ;)

Comment: Then it's in your angular **`if`** statements or similar. The outputed code you provided is not what you'd expect from the template.

Comment: Thanks for your help though! I've tried a few things thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left' in css as follows

```
    div.subSection_content {
            width: 100%;
            float:left;
        }
```

**complete code:-**

```
div.table_container {
            background-color: #a9c7e1;
            width: 100%;
        }

        p.table_img_p {
            background-color: #0090c3;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        .table_img_list {
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 720px){
        div.subSection {
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.subSection_content {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
        }

        div.table_container {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That helps clear up the mess of it acting as two individual divs but that does not put them next to each other. I will keep trying things though. Thanks for a suggestion.

Comment: @VarvaraJones you need to tell us what the desired result should be.

Comment: Apologies. On mobile it should be 1 column (two blue boxes one under the other), and on larger views it should be two columns (two blue boxes next to each other). I've done styling of this kind of thing many times before and never had such difficulty styling it. Just looking for suggestions on what is going on that it doesn't want to float on "1 line" next to each other.

Comment: Please give a visual, you have two types of blue boxes, dark and light. They could be considered one blue box as the darker blue appears to be the header of the content in the lighter blue box. Do you want the lighter blue under the darker blue at all times? Then as a group _Liver Damage_ will be above _Kidney Dame_ on mobile and to the left on desktop?

Comment: See the original post for the desired output. Provided an image.